# Multiply the values of a hash by a number, and return 0 for the negative values

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

How do I multiply the *non-negative* number values of a hash by a number (for example: 2) and for the *negative* values just return 0?

For example, with this hash (with variable years keys):

```
hash = {"year2020" => "-2.0", "year2021" => "3.0", "year2022" => "1.0",...}
```

The result would be: (-2.0 gives 0.0, 3.0*2=6.0, 1.0*2=2.0)

```
result = {"year2020" => "0.0", "year2021" => "6.0", "year2022" => "2.0",...}
```

I tried this, but I can not figure out how to get 0 instead of the negative value:

```
hash.map { |k, v| [k, v.to_f * 2] }.to_h
=> {"year2020"=>-4.0, "year2021"=>6.0, "year2022"=>2.0}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) (introduced in Ruby v2.4):

```
hash = {"year2020"=>"-2.0", "year2021"=>"3.0", "year2022"=>"1.0" }
```

```
hash.transform_values { |v| [2*v.to_f, 0].max }
  #=> {"year2020"=>0, "year2021"=>6.0, "year2022"=>2.0}
```

Comment: @Chris This is a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
hash.each do |key, value|
  v = value.to_f
  hash[key] = v <= 0 ? 0.0 : 2.0 * v
end
```

Comment: Works well pjs. Thank you!

Comment: It should be noted that this is destructive (`hash` is modified in place), considering that the question did not ask for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
hash.each do |key,value|
    if value.to_f>=0.0
        hash[key]=(value.to_f*2.0).to_s
    else
        hash[key]="0.0"
    end   
end
```